# How to set the correct path for custom domain for gitlab pages with vuejs?

Tags: css, vue.js, gitlab

I want to set up my custom domain for my gitlab page

I set up my vuejs project as with  `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
pages:
 image: node:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - npm install --progress=false
  - npm run build
  - rm -rf public
  - mkdir public
  - cp -r dist/* public
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  paths:
  - public
 only:
  - master
```

and I added a `vue.config.js` file containing

```
module.exports = module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/<ProjectName>/" : "/",
};
```

Further I was able to set up the my custom domain following the [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/).

my project page is opening fine at `https://<userName>.gitlab.io/<ProjectName>/`

but when I use my custom domain `<myDomain>.com` the page is blank. When I inspect the page

I see the following message

```
Refused to apply style from 
'https://<myDomain>.com/<ProjectName>/css/app.a4f1ea2f.css' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a 
supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

now when I open the site without the project name `https://<myDomain>.com/css/app.a4f1ea2f.css`.
the content of the compressed css is displayed.

when I take out  `publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/<ProjectName>/" : "/",` then `https://<myDomain>.com` works but `https://<userName>.gitlab.io/<ProjectName>/` does not work anymore.

Therefore I assume there is an issue with the path. Namely the `<ProjectName>` causes most likely the problem. How do I set the page correctly? How can I use both domain?

Comment: If your app should be accessible on `<myDomain>.com` , leave the `publicPath` as `"/"`

Comment: But that would mean that the `https://<userName>.gitlab.io/<ProjectName>/` will not ne accessible

Answer (score 1):

When the same app should be accessible on two different domains - in the root of one and on subpath on the other - only solution is probably setting `publicPath` to relative path

[Vue CLI documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

> The value (`publicPath`) can also be set to an empty string (`''`) or a relative path (`./`) so that all assets are linked using relative paths. This allows the built bundle to be deployed under any public path, or used in a file system based environment like a Cordova hybrid app.

The point is if your site uses relative link without leading slash, it should be interpreted by the browser as a path relative to the current path ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/381282)) and as a result, you can deploy under any public path...